# managing periods of time in netlogo

Tags: time, netlogo

This is my first attempt to do something "serious" in Netlogo, and I am trying to do the following:

after a certain tick, my turtles start buying stuff and they fill a list of the prices they paid (the list is individual). I would like them to stop buying if the mean of the list stays below a certain threshold for a certain amount of ticks.

My question is: how can I *count* ticks in such a case?

This is what I thought:

```
ifelse mean exePriceList < exePrice [set exitList lput who exitList]                      
[set exitList []] 

if length exitList > exitTime  [set buy false set sell false set pass      
true]
```

Basically that's what I do: I add an element (I only care of the length of the list) to another list called exitList (which is not a global variable but it's a turtles-own), and I empty the list if the mean becomes higher than the threshold. Then, if the list is longer than the desired amount of ticks, the turtle stops.

It is not working, because the exitList is not filled properly.
What can I do? Is there a smarter way to manage time? This is the code of the whole procedure:

```
 to bull-strategy
 ask turtles with [bull = true] [
 set color green

 if ticks >= HFAentranceTime + startChecking [


  if mean exePriceList > exePrice + (exePrice * stopLossBull) [set buy false 
  set sell false set pass true]


ifelse mean exePriceList < exePrice [set exitList lput who exitList] [set   
exitList []] 
  if length exitList > exitTime  [set buy false set sell false set pass 
true]

]
]
end
```

Comment: You use a list as turtle-variable for checking the time. But why? Do you want to use the list for something else later on? Because otherwise, you could just use a normal counter variable, like                                       ifelse ... [set turtle-exit-time (turtle-exit-time + 1)] [set turtle-exit-time 0]

Comment: Thank you Tyr. I am now using a variable instead of a list, but my problem stil remains: the variable grows incredibly fast, it's like if all the turtles are counting and writing on the same variable, whose value is in fact the same for all turtles.

Comment: exePriceList is turtle-specific, and it is different for each turtle (they don't buy necessarily at every tick and they buy at different prices). Thus the mean of the list should be different for each turtle, and they should individually increase their own counter.

Comment: Sorry, I unintentionally deleted my last comment. I am not sure how I can help further. Generally it should work, that each turtle counts up its own counter. Perhaps some "print" statements could help you to see whats happening during your model run.

Comment: Running the model tick per tick, I noticed that if there are, let's say, 10 turtles with bull true, the variable increases approximately by 10 (or less, if some of those 10 turtles does not meet the condition "mean exePriceList < exePrice"). So it really seems like all (or most of the) bull turtles are increasing one single variable. 
I really appreciate your help, Tyr.

Comment: @sato It sounds like the variable that you are tracking (`exitList`?) is actually declared in `globals`, even though you suggest it is not ...

Comment: I am totally sure it is not! And I am not using exitList anymore, I am using a variable as a counter, and it is declared in the specific properties of the breed who is executing this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could post the solution to my problem, if someone finds himself in the same situation.
It was just a (pretty basic) error in the code, probably due to inexperience (and/or lack of attention), I only noticed it the following day: there was an "ask" in excess. I asked the turtles to follow a procedure and then, in the procedure, I repeated the "ask" command by mistake. 
So basically the turtles were asked to ask things to each other... thus the abnormal increase of the counter.
Thanks for your help.